# R data frames accessing columns through first letter of the column name

Tags: r, dataframe

I am not sure if this is new to R.

```
Year <- c(2001:2010)
salary <- c(rep(21000,10))

X <- data.frame(Year, salary)

X$Year

X$Y

X$s
```

if you see there are no columns named Y or s in this data frame. But R is returning columns based on the first letter of the column name.

This has turned out to be a problem for me in my scripts.

Comment: It is partial matching.  Use `[[`  as it is `x[[i, exact = TRUE]]`

Comment: If you transform X transform X to `data.table` and use `[` you can avoid that problem: `X <- as.data.table(X)  X[Year, ]`